# Memory leak in fragments : activity in ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord

Tags: android, memory-leaks, heap-memory, profiler, memory-leak-detector

I have a SingleInstance activity and having 5 fragments. User can switch between fragments. While switching Android Studio profiler reporting memory leaks as shown in screenshot.

[image]

Note : I can't finish my activity by finish() method because it's my parent activity. And whenever a button click happen I open it with -

```
intentSetting.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

So this calls my activity's onDestroy() and onCreate().

I have 5 fragments and I have same memory leak for all of the fragments. Please help if someone encountered such issue.